# Extra rows on join in sql server

Tags: sql

This query:

```
select distinct a.id, a.caminho, c.indexObr, d.id, d.tamanho, d.mask, d.idName
from gedaidb.dbo.sistema_Documentos as a
join gedaidb.dbo.sistema_DocType as b on a.idDocType = b.id
join gedaidb.dbo.sistema_DocType_Index as c on b.id = c.docTypeId
join gedaidb.dbo.sistema_Indexes as d on c.indexId = d.id
join gedaidb.dbo.sistema_Indexacao as e on a.id = e.idDocumento
where a.id = 97
```

return this resultSet:

```
id  caminho                                                     indexObr    id  tamanho    mask     idName
97  C:\Users\Guilherme\Desktop\Guilherme\Tipo 3\SkypeSetup.exe  0           25  10         NULL     Numérico
97  C:\Users\Guilherme\Desktop\Guilherme\Tipo 3\SkypeSetup.exe  0           26  10         NULL     AlfaNumérico
97  C:\Users\Guilherme\Desktop\Guilherme\Tipo 3\SkypeSetup.exe  1           24  10         NULL     Caracter
```

now if I add e.valor in the query:

```
select distinct a.id, a.caminho, c.indexObr, d.id, d.tamanho, d.mask, d.idName, e.valor
from gedaidb.dbo.sistema_Documentos as a
join gedaidb.dbo.sistema_DocType as b on a.idDocType = b.id
join gedaidb.dbo.sistema_DocType_Index as c on b.id = c.docTypeId
join gedaidb.dbo.sistema_Indexes as d on c.indexId = d.id
join gedaidb.dbo.sistema_Indexacao as e on a.id = e.idDocumento
where a.id = 97
```

I get those rows returned: (the only extra collumn is the last one, valor)

```
97  C:\Users\Guilherme\Desktop\Guilherme\Tipo 3\SkypeSetup.exe  0   25  10  NULL    Numérico    11111
97  C:\Users\Guilherme\Desktop\Guilherme\Tipo 3\SkypeSetup.exe  0   25  10  NULL    Numérico    aaaa111
97  C:\Users\Guilherme\Desktop\Guilherme\Tipo 3\SkypeSetup.exe  0   25  10  NULL    Numérico    ccccc
97  C:\Users\Guilherme\Desktop\Guilherme\Tipo 3\SkypeSetup.exe  0   26  10  NULL    AlfaNumérico    11111
97  C:\Users\Guilherme\Desktop\Guilherme\Tipo 3\SkypeSetup.exe  0   26  10  NULL    AlfaNumérico    aaaa111
97  C:\Users\Guilherme\Desktop\Guilherme\Tipo 3\SkypeSetup.exe  0   26  10  NULL    AlfaNumérico    ccccc
97  C:\Users\Guilherme\Desktop\Guilherme\Tipo 3\SkypeSetup.exe  1   24  10  NULL    Caracter    11111
97  C:\Users\Guilherme\Desktop\Guilherme\Tipo 3\SkypeSetup.exe  1   24  10  NULL    Caracter    aaaa111
97  C:\Users\Guilherme\Desktop\Guilherme\Tipo 3\SkypeSetup.exe  1   24  10  NULL    Caracter    ccccc
```

all the tables joined has a 1-N relationship so as far as I know if there is no N-N relationship I should not be getting those extra rows

What is the theory behind this issue?

Comment: This is normal behavior. Notice you are using `DISTINCT`.

Comment: Same without distinct. No changes

Answer (score 0):

Unless you put an aggregate function (min, max, etc.) on e.valor, or turn table 'e' into a derived-table that will put it into a one-to-one relationship with table 'a', then the resultset you're getting is correct -- e.valor is making those rows different / `distinct` from each other.

gedaidb.dbo.sistema_Indexacao (table 'e') is clearly in (at least) a one-to-many relationship with gedaidb.dbo.sistema_Documentos (table 'a').  As such, you should anticipate the 'many' effect that you're seeing when you bring in the distinct-making values in e.valor (or any other fields from table e, for that matter).

Answer (score 0):

If a table creation/insert statements had been provided then we would have given a try on sqlfiddle. Nonetheless give this a try:- (UNTESTED & logic only, hence test it out and comment please)

Note: you may adjust `x.r` where condition and `order by` within `row_number()` fields as you deem.

```
select x.id, x.caminho, x.indexObr, x.id, x.tamanho, x.mask, x.idName, x.valor
from      
(     
    SELECT  a.id, a.caminho, c.indexObr, d.id, d.tamanho, d.mask, d.idName, e.valor
    row_number() over ( partition by b.val3 e.valor                 
    order by a.id, a.caminho, c.indexObr, d.id, d.tamanho, d.mask, d.idName) r     
    from gedaidb.dbo.sistema_Documentos as a
    join gedaidb.dbo.sistema_DocType as b on a.idDocType = b.id
    join gedaidb.dbo.sistema_DocType_Index as c on b.id = c.docTypeId
    join gedaidb.dbo.sistema_Indexes as d on c.indexId = d.id
    join gedaidb.dbo.sistema_Indexacao as e on a.id = e.idDocumento
    where a.id = 97    
) x     
where x.r > 1 --
```